# One to many relationship not working in Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, sql, aspxgridview

How am I manage to get the Countries in the same row? Is Gridview the wrong way to go? I just want to print out some matches and show the teams, matchtime and matchID...
[image: Relationship]
!
This is the outcome: 
[image: gridview_results]
!

Comment: Why there's a "country" column on the Matches table ? what does it mean ?Is it the host country ?

Comment: Also, are Awayteam_ID and HometeamID, refering to country table or team table ? I think there's a problem with the join query

Comment: There is no Country in the matches table? Read the answer below. There  is nothing wrong in my database.

Comment: Yeah you're right. my mistake, thought the answer makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join table `Countries` twice with different alias names:

```
SELECT M.MatchID,M.Matchtime,C1.Country as HomeTeam, C1.CountryID as HomeTeamID, C1.Group_ID as HomeGroupID,C2.Country as AwayTeam, C2.CountryID as AwayTeamID, C2.Group_ID as AwayGroupID
FROM Matches M JOIN
     Countries C1 ON M.HomeTeam_ID=C1.CountryID JOIN
     Countries C2 ON M.AwayTeam_ID=C2.CountryID
```

**Explanation:**

Here `Countries` table is joined with alias names C1 and C2.

C1 represents the country details of home team. C2 represents the country details of away team.